# Categories in admin interface: can they be collapsible?

Tags: categories, admin

I have many hierarchical categories, some of which have the same names.
Can I add collapsible categories functionality in the category selection widget in the admin interface?

I refer to the categories selection widget next to the posts edit screen in the admin interface.

From my front end (Mozilla, IE, Chrome) this widget is NOT collapsible, but offers a huge linear listing of categories, which is difficult to navigate. If that widget had little crosses to collapse branches, it would be easier to navigate large branches easier.

Comment: Where exactly? Post editor meta box, category manager, term editor …?

Comment: Post editor box, where you select the category/ies of the post.

Comment: Do you mean a dropdown with the categories? In which case, you'll only be able to select one...

Comment: No, I mean a collapsible tree from which I will be able to select many different categories. 
Tree should initially be closed so that I navigate easily across major branches.